# Elements apear only after inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have just encountered the strangest problem I've ever come across in my humble web developing freelance career. I'm building a web application for a job application site where applicants use their webcams to answer 3 short questions. For this I use a jQuery plugin called [ScriptCam](http://scriptcam.com) which uses Flash to activate the user's webcam. I had this all working just fine but now I have the following problem.

I use jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` to show and hide buttons. One button, a replay button, doesn't show up when calling `$("#replay").show();` but DOES show when I right click anywhere in the browser after calling this command and hit "Inspect Element"! I've been searching for what could cause this problem but haven't found anything... What could cause this behavior?

This is how I have defined the button:

`<div onclick='replay();' id='replay' class="replay">Replay</div>`

This is the button's CSS:

```
.replay{
    float: left;
    top: 150px;
    left: 60px;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 36px -16px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background:url('../img/button-grey.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    color: white;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Archive;
    display: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Edit: This is CSS of the button's parent div:

```
.box{
    margin-left: 100px;
    height: 337px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I haven't used any delays anywhere and the button really appears only right after I click inspect element somewhere in the browser. I also cannot reproduce this problem anywhere else. Anyone got an idea what could cause this? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Update: It appears that only Safari on Mac is having issues.

Update 2: When moving the button out of it's parent div to directly below the body tag it works as it should! So it's probably a css conflict of the parent div?

Edit: You can see the problem live [here](http://mickvj.com/psfm/?persnr=29&key=9f693fb58676a29d7aa795e177959e04#), just hit the button "Volgende vraag" en wait for the small video to finish. After that the replay button should appear right above the video.

Comment: Please post also your jQuery code and if possible a jsfiddle with a example so we can see the problem.

Comment: That sounds like a redraw issue. If you resize the page, does that also make it work?

Comment: Rending issue ... this is probably a browser bug

Comment: @MatthewR. Unfortunately resizing the browser doesn't work.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy you're probably right, the problem only appears in Safari and not in Chrome or Firefox! It's still a problem though... Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy I've found that issues like this are often down to incorrect markup.

Comment: We definitely need to see the jQuery code before we really have a hope.

Comment: @MickvJ, If I were you, I'd start commenting out large blocks of HTML that are irrelevant to this issue (so you're left with just the button and the window). Then test each time.

Comment: @Sergio I have a lot of jQuey code but the code involved here is basically only the .show(); command. A jsfiddle probably doesn't reproduce the problem. It could be a CSS problem since there's quite a lot of it involved...

Comment: @Prisoner I guess that's the only way to find out. Since it's one big HTML document sifting trough it will probably take some time... Any thoughts on it being a Safari only problem?

Comment: @MickvJ Have you tried calling `.show()` in the console and seeing if it works there?  Have you put break points in too see if perhaps it does show it, and then later something hides it?

Comment: @user2532739 Haven't tried that yet! I'll do that first thing tomorrow since it's already 01.30 in the morning here (the Netherlands).

Comment: I meant *rendering* Is there a way we could see it live?

Comment: Post a live link then, otherwise it can be so many things... difficult to help you.

Comment: @Sergio You can see the problem live [here](http://mickvj.com/psfm/?persnr=29&key=9f693fb58676a29d7aa795e177959e04)

Comment: I had a similar problem, which was solved by tweaking the CSS. Not the best answer but try putting the replay button in a container div and then .show() that instead?

Comment: I've updated the question above: it turns out that when I move the button out of it's parent div to directly below the body tag it works as it should. Could this be a css conflict on the parent div?

Comment: @MickvJ, after the first video I do get a `div#replay1` in the screen without me clicking no-where. In the top left corner of the screen. `position:absolute; left:0; right:0;` It just shows once. Can't make it show twice, is that the problem? not showing more than once? I'm on windows/chrome

Comment: @sergio You're right, that's how it should work! Only for testing purposes I moved the button to right below the body tag which seems to help. I've moved the button back to it's original location and the problem is back I guess the parent div is the causing the problem.

Comment: @MickvJ, what you mean with "below the body tag"?

Comment: @Sergio I meant right after opening the `<body>` tag, before any other body elements. But that was just for one minute of testing, I've put it back to it's original location.

Comment: @MickvJ, just read your edit now. Is this problem just on Mac/Safari?

Comment: What is the parent element from this button? What is the CSS of that parent? I suppose this might be a problem with the child element depending on the CSS of the parent, and the parent depending on the CSS of the child.

Comment: @Sergio It appears to be a Safari online issue indeed!

Comment: @Sumurai8 The button is inside a div with `class='box'`, I've added it's CSS above.

Comment: I've found the solution! The problem is caused by the upper container div which has the CSS `display:none`. Although I change that with jQuery's `.show()` and it's contents are visible, removing `display:none` in my CSS makes it work! Thanks for all the great help and suggestions!

Comment: You have more css for your tags than you need to properly style them. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you let it float? There is no need for top and left css properties (it can only mess things up).

Comment: @Sumurai8 You're absolutely right. This is the result of me trying to solve the problem for hours. Also the design has changed a lot over time so a lot of CSS properties are now obsolete. Next step is clean everything up.

Answer (score 10):

I've found the solution! The problem is caused by an earlier container div which has the CSS `display:none`. Although I change that with jQuery's `.show()` before the problem occurs and it's contents are visible, removing `display:none` in my CSS makes it work! Thanks for all the great help and suggestions!

Comment: I have the same problem , But not found display:none .. i got a lightslider from github , then i found the same problem.. nightmare

Comment: thank you so much for posting this answer it was driving me crazy. I think it happens usign an older version of jquery. On v2+ it finds hidden elements ok.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to change the visibility of an element that I found hidden above the image in my stylesheet to fix the issue. I found it by using inspect-element.
Then after changing it the image moved up obviously so I had to change the margins to change it back to its original position.

Comment: "Fixed it eventually though" is for sure not an **answer** that future readers would tell anything. So: if you want to really keep up this answer: consider improving it; otherwise it is not of much help to anybody and should rather be deleted!#