# Button in iFrame does not work in IE but works after inspecting element

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a simple button in my application.

### Page.aspx

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="main" runat="server">
    <form runat="server">
        <button id="btnStart" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server">Start</button>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

### Page.aspx.cs

```
public void btnStart_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do some work

    Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx");
}
```

This `Page.aspx` gets called from a php site and it displays `Page.aspx` in an iFrame. I don't have the code for that but I can ask if necessary.

### Problem is ...

The Start button does not work in IE (IE 11) but it WORKS in Chrome and FireFox.

Also, sometimes when the iFrame gets called for the first time, it works just once. But after closing the iFrame and open the iFrame again, the Start button does not work any more.

Another thing is that when I right click the iFrame page (Page.aspx) and click `Inspect element`, then the Start button always works.

### What I've tried

I did find some similar questions like this ([Elements appear only after inspect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243427/elements-apear-only-after-inspect-element)). And I tried removing all `divs` that surrounds the button and also tried removing classes for the button but did not work for me.

I've also tried adding this to `Global.aspx.cs`

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p", "CP=\"CAO PSA OUR\"");
```

as someone suggested that sessions get blocked from traversing the iFrame, but again it did not work for me.

For some reason, if it's after inspecting element, it works fine consistently. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are both the main page and iframe on the same domain and port?

Comment: domain is the same. The main page that calls my page is `https://www.main.com` and my page is `https://sub.main.com`. I'm not sure about the port..

Comment: Is the p3p on the iframe or main page? It needs to be on the iframe response

Comment: I put the `p3p` in my page, which is the iFrame page.